# how did my nginx conf get into an alternate location

Tags: arch-linux, nginx

I spent days tracking down why the default home page served via `nginx`; no matter how I defined my conf, it wasn't changing.  I grepped to hell and back, and finally today, a result from hell, hell replied on a grep with `/srv/http/etc/nginx`.

**Where would this come from, can anybody please speculate?**  It's possible I did something and don't remember, it's been a while, but I couldn't find a tutorial online that explains it.  **Is this a legit place for it?**

Note I do use `/srv/http/www` in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file as root path for my main site.  I'm not sure if it could be insanely mapping from there or something, otherwise I don't know how the configs got there unless I  manually accidentally moved them there, but **how are they actually working if that's the case?**

The default page does load.  That page is oddly following the same alternate location pattern since its located in `/srv/http/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`, thus it looks like the entire installation of nginx was done into `/srv/http` or something.

**Is there a person in there who spots where it's coming from**, or if they feel I did a manual move somewhere?

Comment: `pacman -Qo /srv/http/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` will tell you which package installed that file.  That is, given that it was installed by pacman.  `file /proc/<PID of nginx running>/exe` will tell you which `nginx` binary is running.

Comment: Yeah, i saw that looking for which binary, but i think the process remapped its use of proc, so thought after reading it used an alternate proc(maybe /src/http/etc/proc for all i know, not /proc.  hmm. ii wish i had known that first, i would have known it was chroot right away.

Answer (score 1):

Upon research this looks like it was an installation what was attempted to install into a CHROOT JAIL, since its an arch distro, there is one reference [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#Installation_in_a_chroot) that refers to the `/srv/www` mentioned.

It appears the alternate configuration will need to be used, not the one in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf which now serves as either a mask, alternate use, or dead weight, depending on how you want to look at it.